# data in a select list clears out after adding one more field collection

Tags: ajax, entities, javascript

I have a 2 select list inside the field collection. One is a parent list and another is a child list. Child list is populated when the parent list is selected.I use my custom Ajax and JQuery to achieve this. My field collection is in unlimited valued field the problem is whenever I clicked add another item to make a new field collection my previous selected child list looses its data. Is there any way how to retain the previously selected child list.

My jQuery code:

```
$(".field-name-field-countries .form-select").change(function(){
   $('[id$=field-cities-depend-und]').empty();
    //var id=$(".field-name-field-countries .form-select :selected").text();
    var id=this.id;

    var val=$("#" + id  +" :selected").text();

    var dataString = 'id='+ val;    

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "/sites/all/modules/customs/drop_down/ajax_city.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,


        success: function(json)
        {
             $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                 $('[id$=field-cities-depend-und]').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
            });

        } 
    });

});
```

My Ajax code:

```
<?php


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","d7-demo");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     if($_POST['id']){
       $country=$_POST['id'];
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT country,city FROM cities_link where country='$country'");
       $rows = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
             {              

             //  $data=$row['city'];
               $rows[] = $row['city'];
             // print json_encode($data);
             }
            print json_encode($rows);           
            mysqli_close($con);

    }

?>
```

Comment: You have to show us your custom Ajax and jQuery script. You must be using non-standard non-form-api methods to do this. Otherwise it should have gotten the values from `$form_state`

Comment: @Beebee I used the follow way to do this. Above are the codes that I am using.

Comment: that code is in no way utilizing the standard Drupal ajax framework. I'm afraid if you want this to work properly you'll need to read up: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7 I'm sure people will be happy to assist once you get started. You'll need to use `hook_form_alter` to attach a `#ajax` property to your parent select field and also build the child select field's options in there too by checking if `$form_state['values']['parent_select_list_field_name']` contains a value. And in the ajax callback just return the child select field.

Comment: @Beebee is right that you should use AJAX provided by Drupal for that to work, but I would rather suggest to read [ajax section in Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) first.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, forms are protected from submitting values that was never outputted as available options. When you alter options with custom JavaScript, you are making user to submit values Drupal does not know to be valid. Try to rewrite your code to use [form API `#ajax` parameter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). It will look more complicated indeed, but it'll make Drupal know about changed options.

Remember to make actual changes in form building function. Ajax handler is there only to provide the part of the form that needs to get updated, and maybe do some one-time touch-ups you don't care to keep.